# Oracle RegExp - Dealing with double quotes within the string field

Tags: regex, oracle, csv

The Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR function has been working fine for me in the last months. But suddenly, comes a line with the content:

```
"field 1 "",""","field 2","field 3", "","","","field 7"
```

In this case the expected match information is (https://regex101.com/r/s2v60b/1):

```
field 1: "field 1 "","""
field 2: "field 2"
field 3: "field 3"
field 4: ""
field 5: ""
field 6: ""
field 7: "field 7"
```

Even VS Code knows what I mean, since it splits correctly the fields by colour:
[image]

But when I evaluate the below command in Oracle using the query:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(
      '"field 1 "",""","field 2","field 3", "","","","field 7"' 
    , '(^|,)("((?:""|[^"])*)")', 1, 1, '', 2) TEXT 
FROM DUAL;
```

the `field 1` comes truncated as `"field 1 "`, shifting the remainder fields.

Do you know what I am doing wrong and perhaps correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support non-capturing groups so you can't use `(?:)` just drop the `?:` and make it a capturing group and your code should work (you may need to add `\s*` as you have a space between the comma and the start quote `(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")`).

For example:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS field1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")', 1, 2, NULL, 2 ) AS field2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")', 1, 3, NULL, 2 ) AS field3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")', 1, 4, NULL, 2 ) AS field4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")', 1, 5, NULL, 2 ) AS field5,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")', 1, 6, NULL, 2 ) AS field6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '(^|,)\s*("((""|[^"])*)")', 1, 7, NULL, 2 ) AS field7
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs, for your test data:

> ```
> FIELD1          | FIELD2    | FIELD3          | FIELD4              | FIELD5          | FIELD6 | FIELD7   
> :-------------- | :-------- | :-------------- | :------------------ | :-------------- | :----- | :--------
> "field 1 "",""" | "field 2" | "field 3"       | ""                  | ""              | ""     | "field 7"
> ```

If you want to match quoted and unquoted values, you can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"([^"]|"")*")(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS field1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"([^"]|"")*")(,|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) AS field2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"([^"]|"")*")(,|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) AS field3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"([^"]|"")*")(,|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1 ) AS field4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"([^"]|"")*")(,|$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1 ) AS field5,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"([^"]|"")*")(,|$)', 1, 6, NULL, 1 ) AS field6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"([^"]|"")*")(,|$)', 1, 7, NULL, 1 ) AS field7
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( csv ) AS
SELECT '"field 1 "",""","field 2","field 3", "","","","field 7"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '"field 1.1",2.1,"3.1","field ""4"".1",field5.1,"field ""6"".""1""","""field 7.1"""' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> FIELD1          | FIELD2    | FIELD3    | FIELD4          | FIELD5   | FIELD6              | FIELD7         
> :-------------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------------- | :------- | :------------------ | :--------------
> "field 1 "",""" | "field 2" | "field 3" | ""              | ""       | ""                  | "field 7"      
> "field 1.1"     | 2.1       | "3.1"     | "field ""4"".1" | field5.1 | "field ""6"".""1""" | """field 7.1"""
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f14a0e95df99a8223d75d6714f84e0ff)*